# Insert multiline text into several files via commandline

Tags: bash, shell-script, latex

I want to insert some code into multiple `tex` files `foo*.tex` in a directory, one line after `\documentclass{.*}`. Note that the files have different document classes so the `.*` is just a symbolic placeholder here.

The code has multiple lines, for example

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
```

What's the best way to do this automatically?

Comment: Doesn't TeX have "include"-type directives?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use include in this case

Comment: Sorry, I confused `\begin{document}` with `\documentclass{.*}`. I edited the question to fix this. But then it becomes a bit more complicated because there are multiple documentclasses in the files (for example `article` or `beamer`)

Comment: @student: But `documentclass` also have options with following format: `\documentclass[options]{style}`. Do you mean without any option?

Comment: It would be sufficient without options in this case. But I guess that one could just use a regular expression which matches `\documentclass.*` or something like that, the input code should be placed into a new line anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
/^\\documentclass[^{]*{[^}]*}/ {
    a\
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\
\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\
\\usepackage{ngerman}
}
```

Run it like:

```
sed -s -i.bak -f script.sed foo*.tex
```

I use `^` to match the `documentclass` at the beginning of the line. Remove it if you can have spaces before it.

The `-s` switch considers each input as a different file, and `-i` creates backups with `bak` extension.

Comment: I get `sed: file script.sed line 4: unknown command: \``

Comment: @student: Sorry. An error copying the code. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I confused `\begin{document}` with `\documentclass{...}`. See my edit. Would be nice if you could include this change into your answer.

Comment: @student: Edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

the following shell script should do it

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
/\\begin{document}/ a\
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\
\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\
\\usepackage{ngerman}
' $1
```

simply call the script with your files as input (one by one)